# Python- KeyError: False while filtering from dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python, need little help.
I am reading a json response from the API and converting it into tabular format using below code. The response is having few columns - orderId,price

```
ORDER_REP=pd.DataFrame.from_records(Jsonresponse)
```

I want a price  for specific orderid, I am using below code

```
CE_ORDER_PRICE=ORDER_REP['price'][ORDER_REP['orderId'==1210813001851]]
```

However getting error **KeyError: False**

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the bracket ] after 'orderId' that was causing the issue.

```
CE_ORDER_PRICE=ORDER_REP['price'][ORDER_REP['orderId']==1210813001851]
```